# change entity framework reference in webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, runtime-error, entity-framework-6

I currently have a .Net WebAPI2 project that uses an Entity Framework6 assembly reference. This is my "Production" environment. I created a parallel "Test" environment with a new test sql database (copy of the production db) and a WebAPITest and EFTest as copies of the associated prod VS2013 projets. I was able to change the database to DBTest in the app.config of the new EFTest and that seems to work fine. I changed the reference in WebAPITest to point to the new EFTest assembly and that appears to be wired up correctly. The problem is when I actually run the WebAPITest project in VS2013 and call the WebAPITest controllers, it is still hitting the original EF and API. I also commented out the  in the Web.config of the WebAPITest but it still points to the old connection at runtime.

Creating a new controller in WebAPITest was successful and referencing EFTest all appears to work with no build errors, but running from VS to try the new controller returns and error that the new controller does not exist and any preexisting controller still hits the old EF apparently.

I tried to clear the browser cache with no success.
What other reference locations could I update to resolve this?

App.Config from WebAPITest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="RecTaxEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/RecTaxEFModel1.csdl|res://*/RecTaxEFModel1.ssdl|res://*/RecTaxEFModel1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=myserver;initial catalog=DB;user id=USER;password=PWD;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Web.Config from WebAPITest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301879
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <connectionStrings>
    <!-- <add name="RecTaxEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/RecTaxEFModel1.csdl|res://*/RecTaxEFModel1.ssdl|res://*/RecTaxEFModel1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=myserver;initial catalog=DB;user id=USER;password=PWD;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />-->
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you post `web.config` and any other `.configs` that you may have in here?

Comment: Why is it that you cannot be bothered to use a capital letter to start your question title? Why no question mark in your question title?  Question titles need to be well formed so that the list of questions looks like a list of actual questions.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. It ended up being a typeo in the name of the WebAPI controller I was trying to call from the new test environment.